# Media upload is not working in magento custom module editor

Tags: php, image, magento, upload, module

I have created a custom module in magento which contains a textbox and an editor.
But when I try to upload image or video using editor it is displaying me the error like.

```
error: error in [unknown object].fireEvent():

event name: open_browser_callback

error message: MediabrowserUtility is not defined
```

Because of this I am unable to upload any image or video in my module.

How to solve this problem?
Please Help me..

Comment: It is custom module and no code? How do we know where the error come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config.xml you have:

```
<events>
  <cms_wysiwyg_config_prepare>
    <observers>
      <variable_observer>
        <class>core/variable_observer</class>
        <method>prepareWysiwygPluginConfig</method>
      </variable_observer>
    </observers>
  </cms_wysiwyg_config_prepare>
</events>
```

In Block/Adminhtml/WHATEVER/Edit.php

```
protected function _prepareLayout() {
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled()) {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
    }
}
```

Then in the top of Block/Adminhtml/WHATEVER/Edit/Tab/Form.php

```
     protected function _prepareForm() {
            $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
            $this->setForm($form);
            $wysiwygConfig = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(array('add_variables' => false,
         'add_widgets' => false,
          'add_images' => true,
          'files_browser_window_url' => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg_images/index'),
          'files_browser_window_width' => (int) Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/cms/browser/window_width'),
          'files_browser_window_height'=> (int) Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/cms/browser/window_height')
         ));
```

Further down:

```
            $fieldset->addField('not-called-content', 'editor', array(
                                    'name'      => 'not-called-content',
                                    'label'     => Mage::helper('WHATEVER')->__('Content'),
                                    'title'     => Mage::helper('WHATEVER')->__('Content'),
                                    'style'     => 'width:550px; height:300px;',
                                    'required'  => false,
                                    'config'    => $wysiwygConfig,
                                    'wysiwyg'   => true
                                    ));
```

Standard gotcha: don't call your wysiwyg area 'content'. That is used already by Magento for the form id.