# Magento wysiwyg editor error

Tags: magento, wysiwyg

I am getting the following error when i try to upload media from my magento admin panel.I don't know why i am getting this error.Please help to find out.

[image]

Comment: I think this may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210108/media-upload-is-not-working-in-magento-custom-module-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this error before when the js files in the /js folder have been minified.  Download the same version of Magento you are running,

Backup your js/prototype folder ,and upload this folder from new download